# I want to convert a normal mysql query to codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to convert a normal mysql select query to codeigniter

SELECT count(*) `leave_status`, `teacher_id` FROM `teacher_attendance` WHERE teacher_id='1' & `leave_status`='1' group by `teacher_id`

this is what i have tried

```
$attendance = $this->db->get_where('teacher_attendance', array('year' => $running_year, 'timestamp' => $timestamp, 'teacher_id' => $row['teacher_id']))->result_array();
```

what i want to do is get the count of leave_status by teacher id

Comment: if used `count(*)` you are got one single row. so why `teacher_id`?

Comment: I want to filter the leave_status for particular teacher so i want to use the teacher id? right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select("count(*) as leave_status, teacher_id");
    $this->db->from("teacher_attendance");
    $this->db->where("teacher_id = 1 AND leave_status='1'");
    $this->db->group_by("teacher_id");
    $query = $this->db->get();       
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $result = $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: when i give a print_r() and checks   $result = $query->result_array();                
        print_r($result); it prints a Array ( [0] => Array ( [leave_status] => 1 [teacher_id] => 1 ) ) so how to print only the  [leave_status] => 1,  thanks

Comment: If you want row you can use $query->row().

Comment: when i use $query->row() it returns stdClass Object ( [leave_status] => 1 ) so now i want to give this leave_status to an echo and print it

Comment: `$this->db->where("teacher_id",1)` and `$this->db->where("leave_status", 1);`